# Save data from datagridview to excel file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, datagridview, export-to-excel

i have created function to save data  from datagridview to excel file.

Function to save :

```
 try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
            app.Visible = true;
            worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
            worksheet.Name = "Records";

            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = dataGridView2.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
                        {
                            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = "";
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user. 
                SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                saveDialog.FilterIndex = 2;

                if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName);
                    MessageBox.Show("Export Successful", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                app.Quit();
                workbook = null;
                worksheet = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()); }
```

And it works good on my computer with version :
[image]

I try to run this on my second computer where is installed :

[image]

What i need to change in code to works with both versions?
I'm looking example that will do the same but works on every  office installation.
Btw when i try to run on second computer i have this error :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an answer directly to why your code throws that error. But as an alternative approach that works for me, could be worth trying? I used 'ClosedXML' package from Nuget... There are probably other options out there too like 'yob's reply, that I'm sure would also work fine.

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
```

Then to save data:

```
        SaveFileDialog saveFile1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFile1.Filter = "Excel file|*.xlsx";
        saveFile1.Title = "save results as Excel spreadsheet";
        saveFile1.FileName = title + " -" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".xlsx";
        if (saveFile1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var wb = new XLWorkbook();
            var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(data, title);
            wb.SaveAs(saveFile1.FileName);
        }
```

'data' is a datatable, so you would need to convert the datagridview to datatable first. As I said, not an answer to your existing code, but a possible alternative that works for me :) Good luck.

Comment: Yeah it works good , but now how can i load it into datagridview again from file?

Comment: Have a read of https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-and-Import-Excel-data-to-DataTable-using-ClosedXml-in-ASPNet-with-C-and-VBNet.aspx. Theres an example in there for loading back into your program from excel file using ClosedXML

Answer (score 0):

if you're not bound to use MS Office components, then I'd suggest to use EPPlus library instead.

```
string saveasFileName = .....

using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
{
    using (var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Records"))
    {
        worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Records from dataGridView2:";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        //  column headers
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[2, i + 1].Value = dataGridView2.Columns[i].HeaderText;
        }
        // actual data
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                //  ... populate worksheet ...
                worksheet.Cells[i + 3, j + 1].Value = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value?.ToString()??"";
            }
        }
        // save
        package.SaveAs(saveasFileName);
    }
}
```

I have an example at https://github.com/siccolo/EppPlus_CreateExcel/blob/master/Excel.cs

@Adamszsz - if you need to open an excel file and load into gridview, then you can use oledb connection, for example: - open excel file **.xls**:

```
...
var excelconnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";
var table = "[Sheet1$]"
//  using System.Data.OleDb
var excel = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + table, excelconnection);
var exceldata = new DataTable();
excel.Fill(exceldata);
...
```

while for excel file **.xlsx** use Net.SourceForge.Koogra.Excel2007.